# How to use rospy.wait_for_message

Tags: python, ros, rospy

im using rospy for a project however I dont fully understand how getting messages work.
I have a drone send an specific message every second, but when I try to get the message the program gets stuck (never prints "a"). What am I doing wrong?

```
while(continue):
        ponto_atual = rospy.wait_for_message('/uav1/control_manager/position_cmd',PositionCommand)
        print("a")
        continuar = comparar(ponto_desejado, ponto_atual)
```